# Chaining together 2 Airflow macros

Tags: airflow

There are [two Airflow macros](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/_modules/airflow/macros.html) available currently: `ds_add` and `ds_format`.

I would like to know the syntax for using them both.

For example, I currently can use one of them like this to add 7 days to a date:

```
dt7 = '{{ macros.ds_add(ds, 7) }}'
```

However, I actually need to do something like this and get back a YYYYMMDD format without using `datetime` or any other python package, since I need to feed this into an Operator:

```
dt7_fixed = '{{ macros.ds_add(ds_nodash, 7) }}'
```

But `ds_add` does not support 'YYYYMMDD' format, only 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

A workaround is to `use ds_format` in that one-liner too, but I can't grok the right syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will do what you want:

```
{{ macros.ds_format(macros.ds_add(ds, 7), '%Y-%m-%d', '%Y%m%d') }}
```

You should think of these macros the same way you would think of functions.
As per the link you included above `ds_format` takes in 3 params, date string and two strings representing desired input and output format.

The output of the originally used `ds_add` macro is a string which you can use as the first argument here.

Note in the source that this uses `datetime` under the hood.